# SQL Weekly Results Table Structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, structure

I was wondering if anyone could help me get my head around this problem that I'm having, I have an Excel spreadsheet with the following layout.

```
Area |ID   |Location  |Week1 |Week2 |Week3+
71   |1484 |Rochdale  |713   |728   |690
71   |1485 |Doncaster |713   |728   |690
```

How would I best structure an SQL table to store these, that I could then easily retrieve and display in html?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I have tried to write the code myself, I asked with regards to the table structure as I thought that's where I was going wrong. 

I've currently got this output;

Area Location     Result Week
72         Rochdale    123  1
72         Doncaster   234  1

from this code;

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM locations";

    $result = $conn->query($query);

    $display = "<table border='1'><tr><th>Area</th><th>Location</th><th>Result</th><th>Week</th>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        
        $display = $display."<tr><td>".$row['area']."</td>";
        $display = $display."<td>".$row['location']."</td>";
        $display = $display."<td>".$row['result']."</td>";  
        $display = $display."<td>".$row['week']."</td></tr>";
    }

    $display = $display."</tr></table>";

Comment: What I'm after is for it to be displayed like; 

Area | Location    | Week 1 | Week 2
72    | Doncaster | 123        |234

Answer (score 1):

At its most basic:

```
Area|ID |Location |Week |Value
```

Further optimisation might be required

Comment: LHF @Strawberry?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Any way the wind blows